# What is wrong with my regular expression for replacing the content of HREF links in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a regular expression to replace all occurrences of the substring `">(Some Text)</A>"` with `.html">(Some Text)</A>"` (case insensitive) in an HTML document.

However, it does not appear to produce the intended replacement on the outputted page.

```
Pattern fixRest = Pattern.compile("(\">.*?</a>)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mh2 = fixRest.matcher(pgText);
mh2.replaceAll(".html$1");
```

When I view the outputted page, it appears that there are plenty of `href` links that are not suffixed with a `.html` by this code.

Is there something wrong with my Regex? Running it under RegexBuddy I see it producing the results I expect for the same page that is in the variable `pgText`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mh2.replaceAll(".html$1");
```

isn't modifying `mh2` in place.  Try using the result as in

```
mh2 = mh2.replaceAll(".html$1");
```

---

In general though, don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Here's a sampling of the ways this can fail:

```html
<a href='...'>foo</a>                  <!-- single quotes -->
<a href=...>foo</a>                    <!-- no quotes -->
<a href="..." title="">foo</a>         <!-- the href isn't the last attribute. -->
<a href="..."><img src="...">foo</a>   <!-- tag inside link -->
<a href="..." >foo</a>                 <!-- space between attribute and end -->
<a href="...">"y">"x"</a>              <!-- text node contains '>' -->
```

I'm sure you can think of many more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understand that using Regex in general to parse HTML is bad, but in this assignment it was deemed acceptable by my TA/Prof for the specific test cases he will use